# Problems creating virtual env with different Python version

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, python-venv

I'm working on a big project that needs to be ported from python2.7 to python3.7.
For developing, I rely on virtual envs.

For the 2.7v, I'm using a virtual environment created with the `virtualenv` module and it's packages `virtualenvwrapper`, and `virtualenvwrapper-win`.

For the 3.7v, I tried to create an env by using the same packages, this time I installed them to the python3.7 directory. I managed to set up the python3.7 with its own environmental variable, naming it `python3.exe` so I could chose, where to install additional python packages.

i.e. 
`pip install virtualenv` - to install `Virtualenv` in the python2.7 directory, but

`python3 -m pip install virtualenv` - to install it into the python3.7 directory

```
C:\Users\user1>pip freeze
...
stevedore==1.30.1
virtualenv==16.4.3
virtualenv-clone==0.5.1
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.5
```

vs.

```
C:\Users\user1>python3 -m pip freeze
...
stevedore==1.31.0
virtualenv==16.7.5
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.5
```

So far so good.

When I want to create a virtual env named `envTest` with python3.7, here's the command I use:

`mkvirtualenv python3 envTest`

To avoid any further misidentification, I renamed the new python executable in the local env's folder to `python0.exe`.

Now, I can check the paths and versions of all three available python sources (`python.exe`=python2.7 , `python3.exe`=python3.7, and `python0.exe`= python executable from virtual env).

**BUT**, here is what I get:

```
(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>whereis python
C:\Python27\python.exe

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>whereis python3
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python3.exe

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>whereis python0
C:\Users\user1\Envs\envTest\Scripts\python0.exe

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>python --version
Python 2.7.16

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>python3 --version
Python 3.7.4

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>python0 --version
Python 2.7.16

(envTest) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>
```

It looks to me, like I didn't get the right `virtualenvwrapper` when creating the `envTest` env, and thereby indirectly called the wrong python version.

**How could I fix this?**

I also tried to simply try the python3.x built-in `venv`, but using it, I get an Error message:

```
C:\Users\user1\projects>python3 -m venv ./venv_Test venvEnv
Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

even though it created the following directories, although without python executable

```
C:\Users\user1\projects\venv_Test>dir
...
30.01.2020  14:41    <DIR>          .
30.01.2020  14:41    <DIR>          ..
30.01.2020  14:41    <DIR>          Include
30.01.2020  14:41    <DIR>          Lib
30.01.2020  14:41               117 pyvenv.cfg
30.01.2020  14:41    <DIR>          Scripts
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following steps:

1. I read about the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) `py.exe`.
2. I had to rename my Python3.7 executable from `python3.exe` back to `python.exe` in order to make it executable with `py.exe`.
3. For creating a virtual env with `virtualenv` I used `py.exe` with the following command:

```
mkvirtualenv envTest2 -p C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

everything checks out, now:

```
(envTest2) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>whereis python
C:\Users\user1\Envs\nanopy3\Scripts\python.exe

(envTest2) C:\Users\user1\projects\env_testing>python --version
Python 3.7.4
```